# Native Browser Lazy loading not working as expected- Loads images below the fold/viewport as well

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, viewport

I have updated the current code that my React application uses to lazy load images from Intersection Observer to native browser lazy loading since it is supported by almost all browsers now. I see that it lazy loads images as I keep scrolling and is working. However, on the initial page load, it loads a few more images than expected.

My expectation would be that it would only load the images that are visible on the viewport but a few other images below the viewport get loaded too. Is this expected? All I have done is add the tag `loading = lazy` to the  element.

Also, as I refresh the page, there is an inconsistency in the number of images loaded as well. I can see that the number of images loaded changes with every other page re-load - I was referring to this [work](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/img-loading-lazy) and it seems to be consistent. Any help would be appreciated, please. Thank you for your time.

PS:
I tried checking if ads being rendered on the page were causing these issues but that did not have any effect on the problem above.
The images have height and width set as well.

Comment: @lua_python_java Thank you for responding. But both the links is about Intersection Observer API which I have deprecated from my codebase while moving towards native browser lazy loading.

Comment: I couldn't tell from the wording, my bad. Thanks for letting me know, and I think you may want to add some code/examples of what you're doing and maybe how to replicate! I'd love to help spit ball ideas, just don't have specifics. @Reshma